# Notification Trigger event

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, push-notification, push

I have a social marketing admin for my clients. I want to be able to update the admin when there is a new notification on their facebook fan page or a check in at their location.

Currently facebook sends me an email notification (for example when someone posts on the fan page wall). What I need is for a script to run that updates my admin whenever there is a unread notification.

What I don't want is to have to run a cron job every minute that grabs notifications. I have a lot of clients and a lot of fan pages. This would become very taxing.

Is there a way for facebook to push the notification to my script page instantly instead of querying every minute?

Answer (score 0):

Real-time updates for pages do not cover feed content yet.

> Currently facebook sends me an email notification (for example when someone posts on the fan page wall). What I need is for a script to run that updates my admin whenever there is a unread notification.

You could pipe incoming mail to a script, have it analyze the mail body (what page it was send for), and then trigger the notification …